# how to hide circle copy button on UWP webview (mobile) text selection?

Tags: webview, uwp

I want custom menu to appear in webview while text is selected. By default the circle copy button appears on text selection. How can I override this default behavior?

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you paste your xaml or screenshot so i can understand properly

Comment: I've added screenshot link to my previous post